# How to enter to file with variable that was taken from list - bash

Tags: bash

Lets say that I have a file `myfile.csv`. In this file i have a list like this:

```
black
white
grey
orange
red
```

I want that any row will be an variable and with the variable enter to directory that have this name.

Example:

```
for i in $( myfile.csv ); do
    cd /directory/$i && cat anotherfile.txt
```

Its not work. I will be happy for your help.:)

Comment: Take a look at this FAQ: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: there are no information about the automatic access to directory with the name from the csv list

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem though, your current logic (using the variable containing the directory name as a path fragment) is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to enter a directory to cat a contained file. And looping over all lines of a file is a job for `while` and `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
   if [[ -f "$dir/anotherfile.txt" ]]; then
       cat "$dir/anotherfile.txt"
   else
       printf 'WARNING: %s not found\n' "$dir/anotherfile.txt"
   fi
done < myfile.csv
```

Of course, this works only if your `myfile.csv` file has exactly one directory name per line...

Comment: Nice answer, I think I'd avoid the `-f` test though : I'd rather have an error complaining about the inextistant file than have it silently fail for some entries. Alternatively OP could add an `else` block displaying an error message of course.

Comment: @Aaron: as the expected behavior is not specified by the OP, it is difficult to decide what to do when the file is missing. I do not like crashing things, so let's just warn, instead (answer updated).

Comment: `cat` already prints an error when passed a bad file name so no need to check yourself.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: thanks for adding this information. I gave the warning example as a starting point, just in case the OP wants to do something else.

Answer (score 2):

In shell scripts there is often a way to avoid explicit loops with clever use of available commands. Most commands—`cat` included—accept multiple file names. And if you want to run a command on each line of a file, think `xargs`.

```
xargs -a myfile.csv -d '\n' -I {} cat /directory/{}/anotherfile.txt
```

This will run `cat /directory/{}/anotherfile.txt` for each line of `myfile.csv`, where the curly braces are replaced with the input lines.

From the [xargs(1) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> - `--delimiter=delim, -d delim`
>
>   Input items are terminated by the specified character.  The specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style character escape such as `\n`, or an octal or hexadecimal escape code.
> - `-a file, --arg-file=file`
>
>   Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this
>     option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are run. Otherwise,
>     stdin is redirected from `/dev/null`.
> - `-I replace-str`
>
>   Replace occurrences of *replace-str* in the initial-arguments with
>     names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not
>     terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.
>     Implies `-x` and `-L 1`.